# Alert number of null is less then a specific value

Tags: mysql, sql, vb6

Im trying to make an alert or even just a msgbox when the number of null value in the table "Transactions" table is less than 2. my table transactions has the following columns:
This is the data in my table" Transactions"

```
trans_id     taxi_id     plate_num    body_num     time_in        time_out    trans_date
90001        11001        fdf343        343      10:00:00 AM                 11/11/2013
90002        11004        pgj847        456      11:00:00 AM                 11/11/2013
90003        11005        fng455        008      11:30:00 AM                 11/11/2013
```

As you can see the "time_out" column has no value, how can I count the number of null values in the column "time_out" and if there less than 2 rows with a null value in their column"time_out" a warning or a msgbox will pop up! Thanks in advance. By the way I hardly need this done. :)
This is my code: I know it sucks!

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error Resume Next

Dim qty As Integer
rsglob.Open "(select count(*) from Transactions where time_out is null) Nulls", "(select count(Nulls) from Transactionwhere time_out is null) Nulled, connglob, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic"
    qty = rsglob("Nulled")
    If (qty > 1) Then
        MsgBox "Your quantity entered exceeds the current unit stock of the product"

        Exit Sub
    End If

Call connect
sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM Transaction where trans_id > 90000 "

rsglob.Open sqlquery, connglob
Set DataGrid1.DataSource = rsglob

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need following sql queries:

1) For counting the number of null values in the column "time_out":

> select count(*) from Transactions where time_out is null

2) For finding if there less than 2 rows with a null value in the column "time_out":

> select count(*) as NumberOfNulls from Transactions where time_out is
>   null group By time_out  having NumberOfNulls < 2